# Need to identify drive pathway to copy data into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Forgive me if this is too basic, but I'm new to PostgreSQL and am trying to copy data from and to my C drive.  I can't seem to get the drive pathway correct.  I've been using C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents, which seems to be right on my Windows Explorer, but it's saying that there's no such drive.  Am I missing a piece in my pathway that needs to be in there?

COPY char_data_types TO 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\texttest.txt'

Comment: Are you copying from an external server? Is this in psql? If so, you should use `\copy` instead of `COPY` as that will allow you to write to and read from local files even when connected to a remote server. Another thing, try pressing tab to see if it auto-completes your path segments.

Comment: No, just trying to connect to files in my hard drive in PostgreSQL.